# How to declare class fields that have different types depending on the constructor parameters in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm new with Java and I'm trying to implement a class to encapsulate a clinic with a queue to determine the next patient to treat.

When initializing an instance of the class, I want to pass a triage type parameter to the constructor to decide how the clinic will select the next patient (frist in first out, or based on the gravity of the disease). Concretely, I want to have a single `queue` class field that is going to either be a `Queue` or a `PriorityQueue` depending on the triage parameter. I have a hard time to figure how to declare the `queue` field.

```
public enum TriageType {
    FIFO,
    GRAVITY
}

public class Clinic {

    public TriageType triageType;

    // This code block doesn't work, but it's the kind 
    // of behavior that I want
    if (triageType == TriageType.FIFO) {
        Queue<Patient> queue = new LinkedList<>()
    }
    else {
        PriorityQueue<Patient> queue = new PriorityQueue<>()
    }

    public Clinic(TriageType _triageType) {
        this.triageType = _triageType;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this without using two distinct classes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A bit of code clean up:   Make `triageType` a non-public member. Also, declare  `Queue<Patient> queue;` there and make it non-public.  The 'if ... else ...` should be moved to inside the constructor:  `if (triageType == TriageType.FIFO) { queue = new LinkedList<>();} else {queue = new PriorityQueue<>();}`

Comment: Thank you ! I think this answers the question that I asked in my comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot determine the static type of the field at runtime. Instead, you would use a common supertype, in this case `Queue` as the type.

If that doesn't fit your needs, say if you need to use methods specific to `PriorityQueue`, the right solution would be to use polymorphism for this, declaring two separete classes, e.g., `FIFOClinic` and `GravityClinic`, which both declare the queue as they require it. The public methods that these classes would have in common should be extracted to a `Clinic` interface.

While the `Clinic` interface can be used in all instances where the public methods are called, the two classes have to be explicitly referenced during construction. If you require the construction to be uniform, i.e., depend only on a `TriageType` parameter, you could use the [abstract factory pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstract-factory-pattern).

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the supertype thing and yes, I only need to use methods that are common between Queue and PriorityQueue. Does this mean that I can simply declare my field queue with `Queue queue;` and in my constructor I initialize it with `queue = new PriorityQueue<>();` ?

Comment: Exactly, just like that :)